# How do I turn key value pairs in object into array of objects?

Tags: javascript

I have some code that outputs an object with key value pairs. Like so:

```
{"a" : "1", "b" : "2", "c" : "3"}
```

I would like to change that output to this instead:

```
[{"a" : "1"}, {"b" : "2"}, {"c" : "3"}]
```

I have fiddled around with Object.entries(), Object.assign() and Array.map() without getting much further. I have put so much time into this now so I figured it was time to ask for some help.

The initial data is from req.query which I have then managed to convert from:

```
{a: "1", b: "2", c: "3"}
```

into

```
{"x.a": "1", "x.b": "2", "x.c": "3"}
```

This will eventually become a mongoDB query.

Below is what I have so far.

```
let obj = Object.entries(req.query);
obj = obj.map(([key, val]) => ["x."+ key, val]);
let newobj = Object.assign(...obj.map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v })));
```

which gives:

```
{"x.a": "1", "x.b": "2", "x.c": "3"}
```

so, as per my initial question. How do I turn this into:

```
[{"x.a" : "1"}, {"x.b" : "2"}, {"x.c" : "3"}]
```

Comment: i know this code is not pretty and there is likely a number of ways to shorten this down...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Object.entries` and `map`

```js
let obj = {
  "a": "1",
  "b": "2",
  "c": "3"
}

let final = Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => ({
  [`x.${k}`]: v
}))

console.log(final)
```

If you just want key instead of `x.a`, you can use simply use

```
 [k] : v
```

Comment: No dupe available at all?

Comment: @mplungjan sorry not so good at finding them, if you found something you have my vote also there

Comment: Add mongo and they will even be closer

Comment: @mplungjan okay thanks :) what this line means  `Add mongo and they will even be closer` ?

Comment: `This will eventually become a mongoDB query.` so I added mongo to the search and found more conversions from array to mongoDB arrays

Comment: @mplungjan ohh i see, learnt something new :)  thanks mate :)